# How to efficiently find all combinations in a multi dimensional array/list in scala?

Tags: arrays, scala, combinations

I have an array,

Array(Array(A, B), Array(I, J), Array(M, N), Array(P))

Please help to find out all possible combinations among them as follows.
Thanks in advance.

```
 ( A , I )
 ( A , J )  
 ( B , I )  
 ( B , J )  
 ( A , M )  
 ( B , M )  
 ( B , N )  
 ( A , P )  
 ( B , P )  
 ( I , M )  
 ( I , N )  
 ( J , M )  
 ( J , N )  
 ( I , P )  
 ( J , P )  
 ( M , P )  
 ( N , P )  
 ( A , I , M )
 ( A , I , N )
 ( A , J , M )
 ( A , J , N )
 ( B , I , M )
 ( B , I , N )
 ( B , J , M )
 ( B , J , N )
 ( A , I , P )
 ( A , J , P )
 ( B , I , P )
 ( B , J , P )
 ( A , M , P )
 ( A , N , P )
 ( B , M , P )
 ( B , N , P )
 ( I , M , P )
 ( I , N , P )
 ( J , M , P )
 ( J , N , P )
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Have you attempted to solve this problem? If you have, include your code and research in your question to show what hasn't worked for you. If not, you should attempt to solve it yourself first and then post the code and research here. It makes your question easier for others to answer too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do it:

```
val input = List(List("A", "B"), List("I", "J"), List("M", "N"), List("P"))

val result =
  (2 to input.size).toList.flatMap {
    combSize => input.combinations(combSize).flatMap {
      comb =>
        comb.dropRight(1).foldRight(comb.takeRight(1).transpose) {
          (el, accum) =>
            accum.flatMap(accEl => el.map(_ :: accEl))
        }
    }.toList
  }
```

Results:

```
List(A, I)
List(B, I)
List(A, J)
List(B, J)
List(A, M)
List(B, M)
List(A, N)
List(B, N)
List(A, P)
List(B, P)
List(I, M)
List(J, M)
List(I, N)
List(J, N)
List(I, P)
List(J, P)
List(M, P)
List(N, P)
List(A, I, M)
List(B, I, M)
List(A, J, M)
List(B, J, M)
List(A, I, N)
List(B, I, N)
List(A, J, N)
List(B, J, N)
List(A, I, P)
List(B, I, P)
List(A, J, P)
List(B, J, P)
List(A, M, P)
List(B, M, P)
List(A, N, P)
List(B, N, P)
List(I, M, P)
.....
```